# Where should node be installed and how to set the PATH?

Tags: node.js, bash, path, npm

I am trying to get yeoman/grunt to work, but I think I am having issues with my path or locations that things are installed. When I run node -v, I get: 
-bash: node: command not found

I had installed things and initially it seemed like it was working. Not sure what broke it, but now it doesn't seem to know what nom, node or yo are.

I think my yo, npm, node, grunt, bower files are installed in the following location:
HD > Users > brian > local > bin > yo

node_modules is at: 
HD > Users > brian > local > bin > node_modules

My .bashrc file has the following in it:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH
```

.bash_profile has this in it:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

My question now is where my files should be installed if they are globally installed, and second if these .bash_profile and .bashrc files are correct?

Thank you so much in advance for any help with this!

Answer (score 0):

A common way to install Node.js is using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). I wrote a [gist](https://gist.github.com/reillysiemens/9362079) a couple of weeks ago on how to install Node.js through nvm and use npm to install new packages like yo (my example is for [bower](http://bower.io/), but the principle is the same). You might find it useful.

The `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` snippets you've shared look like they're for [rvm](https://rvm.io/), a tool similar to nvm, but for [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) instead of [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)